# DNS does not work correctly in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am deploying statefulset in my local PC (for doing research) follow this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/)

In this step:

```
kubectl run -i --tty --image busybox:1.28 dns-test --restart=Never --rm  
nslookup web-0.nginx
```

I meet this error:

```
nslookup web-0.nginx
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'web-0.nginx'
```

My pod and node are still working correctly and my coredns is running correctly

```
kube-system   coredns-fb8b8dccf-hbrhw           1/1     Running   0       26m
kube-system   coredns-fb8b8dccf-rmrwp           1/1     Running   0       26m


nguyen@kmaster:~/Documents$ kubectl get --all-namespaces=true -o wide pods
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       busybox                           1/1     Running   1          65m   10.244.1.218      knode     <none>           <none>
default       web-0                             1/1     Running   0          75m   10.244.1.215      knode     <none>           <none>
default       web-1                             1/1     Running   0          75m   10.244.1.216      knode     <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-fb8b8dccf-hbrhw           1/1     Running   0          51m   10.244.1.219      knode     <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-fb8b8dccf-rmrwp           1/1     Running   0          51m   10.244.0.37       kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-kmaster                      1/1     Running   20         20d   192.168.146.132   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kmaster            1/1     Running   514        20d   192.168.146.132   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kmaster   1/1     Running   144        20d   192.168.146.132   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-ndpjq       1/1     Running   0          76m   192.168.146.129   knode     <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-s2vhp       1/1     Running   0          76m   192.168.146.132   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-dk5jd                  1/1     Running   6          20d   192.168.146.132   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-ts79l                  1/1     Running   2          20d   192.168.146.129   knode     <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kmaster            1/1     Running   172        20d   192.168.146.132   kmaster   <none>           <none>

nguyen@kmaster:~$ kubectl get svc 
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   21d
nginx        ClusterIP   None         <none>        80/TCP    6h8m
```

Did I miss something? Someone can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Please include the output of `kubectl get pods -l app=nginx` as if they're not running, there will be no DNS entry for them; actually the output of `kubectl get --all-namespaces=true -o wide pods` would be super helpful

Comment: IP addresses of your pods are interesting, Some of them are in 10.244.1.x network which is the range for flannel but some of them are in 192.168.146.x network? Also restart number of flannel is 0 but for other system pods the number is huge. I think you tried something in the cluster, i'm not sure but this can be the cause.

Comment: Hi Yavuz, because I tried to delete and create again the flannel network, so the number of restarts is 0

Answer (score 1):

nginx statefulset is deployed in default namespace as shown below

```
default       web-0                             1/1     Running   0          75m   10.244.1.215      knode     <none>           <none>
default       web-1                             1/1     Running   0          75m   10.244.1.216      knode     <none>           <none>
```

This is how you should test

```
master $ kubectl get po
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-0     1/1       Running   0          1m
web-1     1/1       Running   0          1m

master $ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   35m
nginx        ClusterIP   None         <none>        80/TCP    2m
master $ kubectl run -i --tty --image busybox:1.28 dns-test --restart=Never --rm
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup nginx
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      nginx
Address 1: 10.40.0.1 web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 10.40.0.2 web-1.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
/ #
/ # nslookup web-0.nginx
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      web-0.nginx
Address 1: 10.40.0.1 web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local

/ # nslookup web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.40.0.1 web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: thank you. I tried, but it still does not work!
    
    nslookup: can't resolve 'web-0.default'

Comment: You also tested in local PC?

Comment: yes, i tested in my environment and attached the logs

Comment: web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local

Comment: Test nslookup using above pod dns

Comment: Thank you, But it still "cannot resolve" Mr. Ekambaram. I think the problem is not the command, because I tested with other applications, it also "cannot resolve" with dnlookup.

Comment: Hi, [nguyennd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6683327/nguyennd) could you please start with new setup - as state above bu the community it seems very possible there are other issues in your setup. Please share with your results to the community.